# Shadowbox <a> link to target parent window?

Tags: javascript, shadowbox

I'm a n00b when it comes to JavaScript and the DOM... once I've opened up an HTML file in a shadowbox, how do I make an `a href` link or submit a form from the shadowbox into the parent window?  I'm using Rails to build my forms, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming shadowbox is an IFrame powered dialog box system. In that case,

`target="_parent"` or `target="_top"`

should work.